# In Swift, why is CodingKey the protocol I see being used with enums for use of the Codable protocol on a struct?

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, codable

In Swift, why is CodingKey the protocol I see being used with enums for use of the Codable protocol on a struct?

I haven't tested this in too many ways, but I consistently am getting this error trying to replicate all the examples I am finding. I get perfect behavior out of just using the Codable protocol on an enum.

```
// This throws Error
struct Foo: Codable { //! Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol 'Codable'

    var id: String
    var name: String
    var type: MyType
    var order: Int

    enum MyType: String, CodingKey {
        case this
        case that
        case and
        case theOtherThing
    }

}

// This doesn't
struct Foo: Codable {

    var id: String
    var name: String
    var type: MyType
    var order: Int

    enum MyType: String, Codable {
        case this
        case that
        case and
        case theOtherThing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why to use Coding key?*

> If the keys used in your serialized data format don't match the
>   property names from your data type, provide alternative keys by
>   specifying String as the raw-value type for the [CodingKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)
>   enumeration.

**Example:-**

**Json -**

```
    let jsonExample = """
 {
        "id":1,
        "name_Of_person":"jack",
        "emailId":"Demo@apple.com"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

**Create `struct` which conforms to `Codable` protocol**

```
struct UserData: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var email: String
    //Set JSON key values for fields in our custom type
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id //Leave it blank because id matches with json Id
        case name = "name_Of_person"
        case email = "emailId"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        email = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
    }
}
```

**Usage-**

```
 //Decode struct using JSONDecoder

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let modelResult = try jsonDecoder.decode(UserData.self,from: jsonExample)
        print("id is \(modelResult.id) - Name is \(modelResult.name) - email is \((modelResult.email))")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: The documentation surrounding this stuff needs to be better, or I just need to start becoming more involved in the development of Swift community.

Answer (score 3):

Every property of struct Foo must be Codable. That includes `MyType`. `CodingKey` specifies what strings will be used in the JSON dictionary and is not equivalent to Codable. The id, name, order fields are already Codable; provided by the standard library.

**UPDATE**
Add this extension to Foo to change how the structure field labels are encoded/decoded to JSON. I have arbitrarily prepended my_ to two of your properties.

```
extension Foo {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
    case type = "my_type"
    case order = "my_order"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does it specify which strings will be used? Can you give a quick use case? Thanks!!